# HTML variable for URL

Tags: html, variables

I have a web page with 6 streaming IP cams.
Part of the code below:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://172.28.###.##:102"><img src="http://172.28.###.##:102/videostream.cgi?user=username&pwd=password" width="400" 
height="300">
```

When my IP changes, I need to edit the above IP times 6. I've searched for some kind of variable to use so I could just make the one change for all six cams.

Below does not work but I included it to show you what I'm trying to do.

```
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var server = "172.28.###.##";
var url = "http://" + server + ":102/videostream.cgi?user=username&pwd=password";
</script>
</head> 
<body> 
<a href = "<script>" url "</script>"
</body> 
</html>
```

Can something like this be done? Or any other way?

Comment: Look up JavaScript, PHP, Python, Perl, CFM, or any of the other multitudinous scripting languages that can be used alongside or embedded within HTML. Look up static site generators and templates. This is not a new problem and a Google search would reveal HUNDREDS of solutions.

Comment: If you do it on server that supports php, you can set up PHP variables and then do echoing. Or you can use jquery to expand some div. For example, <div id='camera1'></div> <div id='camera2'></div> and jquery $("#camera1").html("You html link code here, like <a href=..");

Comment: Google for jquery html.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but you're mixing JavaScript with HTML.  This doesn't interpret the way you think it would:

```
<a href = "<script>" url "</script>"
```

Consider the HTML and the JavaScript as two separate things.  Build the HTML markup, then use JavaScript code to target and modify elements within that markup.  For example, you might have HTML elements like this:

```
<a id="camLink1" target="_blank" href="http://172.28.###.##:102">
<img id="camImage1" src="http://172.28.###.##:102/videostream.cgi?user=username&pwd=password" width="400" height="300">
```

Notice their `id` values.  As long as those values are unique within the entire page, you can target those values and update attributes on the HTML elements.  Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("camLink1").href = "http://172.28.12.34:102"; 
document.getElementById("camImage1").src = "http://172.28.12.34:102/videostream.cgi?user=username&pwd=password";
```

Putting this together, you can construct a rudimentary script where you have different `id`s for your links/images and use a single variable to set them:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var server = "172.28.###.##";
    var url = "http://" + server + ":102/videostream.cgi?user=username&pwd=password";

    document.getElementById("camImage1").src = url;
    // and so on, for the different elements
</script>
```

One additional thing to note here is that the HTML and JavaScript is evaluated in the order in which it's loaded on the page, so you'll want this JavaScript code to be *after* the HTML elements it targets, otherwise `getElementById()` won't find the elements you're looking for.  So just put the JavaScript `script` block at the bottom of the page.

As you develop this code, you'll find that you can probably reduce some duplication and perhaps define some patterns to allow you to more easily maintain this without so much copy/paste code.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "put the link here";
</script>
......
<script>
document.write('<a href="' + url + '">Link</a>');
</script>
```

JQuery:

```
<a class="link">Link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "link";
$('.link').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', url);
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$url = "link";
?>
......
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Link</a>
```

I would recommend using the PHP, since javascript and jquery will fail if the browser don't allow javascript.